# Why apparently quran 2:29, 41:9-11, and 79:27-30 are in contradiction?

Tags: quran, tafseer, hadith-interpretation

9. Say (O Muhammad ): “Do you verily disbelieve in Him Who created the earth in two Days and you set up rivals (in worship) with Him? That is the Lord of the ‘Alamin (mankind, jinns and all that exists). 10. He placed therein (i.e. the earth) firm mountains from above it, and He blessed it, and measured therein its sustenance (for its dwellers) in four Days equal (i.e. all these four ‘days’ were equal in the length of time), for all those who ask (about its creation). 11. Then He Istawa (rose over) towards the heaven when it was smoke, and said to it and to the earth: “Come both of you willingly or unwillingly.” They both said: “We come, willingly.” 41:9-11

Here the order of creation is first heaven was created then mountains and sustainance was put on earth and then heaven was created.

27. Are you more difficult to create, or is the heaven that He constructed? 28. He raised its height, and He has equally ordered it, 29. Its night He covers with darkness, and its forenoon He brings out (with light). 30. And after that He spread the earth; 31. And brought forth therefrom its water and its pasture. 32. And the mountains He has fixed firmly; 79:27-31

Here the order have changed i.e. first heaven was created then earth was spread out then mountains and sustainance was put on earth.

It seems a little contradictory. I'm confused. Can please someone clarify?

Comment: There are probably many questions on this exact topic on the site.

Comment: http://blog.fussilat.com/was-the-heaven-or-earth-created-first/

Answer (score -1):

Allah mentions first in Quran 41(9->11):

> "created the earth in two Days"

Then He mentions the mountains :

> "He placed therein (i.e. the earth) firm mountains from above it" [...] "in four Days equal"

Then He mentions the heaven, as in the sky, or more modernly, the atmosphere :

> "towards the heaven when it was smoke, and said to it and to the earth: “Come both of you willingly or unwillingly.” They both said: “We come, willingly."

Allah mentions in Quran 79(27->32):

> "is the heaven that He constructed"[...] And after that He spread the earth"

This isn't the universe either, because in 29, Allah mentions the night and day:

> "Its night He covers with darkness" "and its forenoon He brings out (with light)"

So according to surah 41, the Earth was made, and then the mountains, and then the atmosphere. But according to Surah 79, the atmosphere was made, and then the Earth was "spread", and then the mountains were erected. It seems contradictory and confusing.

But we should see that "towards the heaven when it was smoke", the atmosphere already existed, but it wasn't *with* the Earth.

**So Allah made the Earth, then the atmosphere, then He spread the Earth, and then He made the mountains, and then the atmosphere was connected with the Earth.** This agrees with all the verses.

It seems contradictory because the link between the two verses doesn't exist. The link would be the creation of the atmosphere, or the *heaven*.

Comment: Why downvote this ?